# What's the term that refers to the old belief that kings/leaders are born superior and are bound by nature to lead?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, history

I vaguely recall coming across a term in one of my past world history classes that refers to an ideology which stipulates that monarchs are destined from birth to lead and that they descend from greatness, or that they are naturally superior to others.

The best terms I can come up with to describe what I'm thinking of are *natural sovereignty* and *sovereign destiny*, but neither of these bring up relevant information in google. I'm positive there's a technical term for this, but I can't remember what exactly it is.

Here's a relevant example in literature, taken from *The Count of Monte Cristo*, which may help:

> But the kings of modern times, restrained by the limits of mere
>   probability, have neither courage nor desire. They fear the ear
>   that hears their orders, and the eye that scrutinizes their actions.
>   **Formerly they believed themselves sprung from Jupiter,
>   and shielded by their birth**; but nowadays they are not
>   inviolable.

Comment: You may be looking for "the divine right of kings." --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_right_of_kings

Comment: DIVINE RIGHT! Yes, that's it! :)

Comment: I'm thinking there's also a 50-cent word for this, but it's not coming to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the History SE site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, to be fair, the question is less about history and more about a term request

Comment: History has a 'terminology' tag which, I'd say, is far more appropriate. The test is 'Is this word / phrase likely to be used in a context other than a historical / philosophy of history one?'

Comment: Gotcha, make sense.

Comment: The Thai king's jubilee in 2006 was described in the Telegraph (UK newspaper) as a celebration of the divine right of kings. The Independent (UK newspaper) reported that Elizabeth II believes in a version of it (and so will never abdicate). Also she was sacramentally anointed  on June 2nd 1953. Not, I suggest, purely historical.    http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/asia/thailand/1521190/Royals-gather-for-Thai-kings-diamond-jubilee-party.html  http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/queen-uk-republicans-sapphire-jubilee-65-years-coronation-elizabeth-ii-a7565431.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Divine right of kings

The entry in the [Oxford Dictionary online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/divine_right_of_kings) states:

> The doctrine that kings derive their authority from God not their subjects, from which it follows that rebellion is the worst of political crimes. It was enunciated in Britain in the 16th and 17th centuries under the Stuarts and is also associated with the absolutism of Louis XIV of France.

There is also a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_right_of_kings) on this topic where further information can be found.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm hesitant to accept your answer because it's just a restatement of what MDHunter said in the comments

Comment: @AleksandrH Your perogative. I hadn't read MDHunter's comment. If I had I might have drawn his attention to the comment box injunction not to answer questions in comments. One reason for this is exactly your response. This means the question is listed in the index as not having been accepted. If I had seen his comment and been detered from answering (and others too) then the question would have been indexed as having no answer. (See also my answer to https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2653/why-are-answers-being-posted-in-the-comments-on-the-question/8171#8171)

Comment: Usually, a comment is given with the understanding that else someone may elaborate on it as an answer and receive credit for it. However, this answer doesn't really provide any more insight into the term than the comment does. Also, comments are not always read, so future readers may miss entirely that this is the answer the OP was looking for. Tough call....

Comment: @CanisLupus — Sorry, I'm not party to that understanding and it does not appear anywhere in the official guidelines to this site. Of course it's up to the individual whether or not they score the answer. I've already explained how and why I answered.

Comment: Without prejudice to my previously stated position, I have added a dictionary definition to my answer to give it a little (Royal?) padding.